# change credit card coding

Tags: vba

I have a mail merge VBA code of:

```
If GetField(oDS, "mCCNumber") <> "" Then
    sCCNumber = Right(GetField(oDS, "mCCNumber"), Len(GetField(oDS, "mCCNumber")) - 12)
```

but now our CC #s are only 4 characters with no tokens, but some still come through with the 16 characters.

how do I change this code to add "OR" 3 characters (some are 3 and others 4).

also, I cannot comment this out to stop this portion

Comment: Why would you ***ever*** mail merge a credit card number? I'd suggest removing your organization from your profile - I'd only consider make a donation using cash at this point.

Comment: ...is this PCI compliant?

Comment: It's about pulling the gift info into a acknowledgement. it's part of the criteria that is pulled out of our Donor database, but never displayed in the letter

Comment: I'd rather comment it out, but it just jumps to the next unrelated line as an error

Comment: You need to clarify the shape of your data. Does `GetField(oDS, "mCCNumber")` always yield a 16-character string like `************9999` and sometimes it's `*************999` and you're trying to extract the digits? And the reason you can't just pull the right-most characters starting at the last index of `*` is because sometimes it's `1234123412341234`? Does `GetField(oDS, "mCCNumber")` contain spaces? e.g. `1234 1234 1234 1234`? If so then working out the last index of `" "` would be a good start.

Comment: `InStrRev` can help.

Comment: FWIW, credit card numbers should be treated as having an arbitrary length ([13-19 according to this source](https://www.freeformatter.com/credit-card-number-generator-validator.html#cardFormats)). Re [PCI compliance](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/pci_fs_data_storage.pdf), the rule is "At a minimum, PCI DSS requires PAN to be rendered unreadable anywhere it is stored – including portable digital media, backup media, and in logs." The fact that you're getting 16 digits via a VBA data connection is what is worrisome...

Answer (score 1):

First, `GetField(oDS, "mCCNumber")` is being dereferenced 3 times in these two lines alone - pull it into its own local variable:

```
Dim ccNumberField As Field
Set ccNumberField = GetField(oDS, "mCCNumber")
```

Actually we're more interested in the field's contents. Your code is making an implicit *default member* call against the `Field` object - but a `Field`'s default property is its [`Code`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.field.code):

> A field's code is everything that's enclosed by the field characters (`{ }`) including the leading space and trailing space characters.

That means the string you're working with is longer than your code is expecting. I'd think you'd be more interested in the `Text` of the field's `Result`:

```
Dim ccNumberFieldValue As String
ccNumberFiedValue = ccNumberField.Result.Text

If ccNumberFieldValue <> "" Then

   '...
```

Now, `ccNumberFieldValue` should hold the field's actual content. I'm not 100% clear from the OP exactly what that contains though. So I'm going to assume one of such:

- Last 4 digits: `**** **** **** 1234`
- Last 3 digits: `**** **** **** *234`
- [Woopsie](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/pci_fs_data_storage.pdf), all 16 digits: `1234 1234 1234 1234`

So the first thing to do is to grab the last 4; `Right$` does that:

```
sCCNumber = Right$(ccNumberFiedValue, 4)
```

That leaves us with either:

- `1234`
- `*234`

From there you can use `IsNumeric` to determine if the entire substring is numeric (assuming there's a non-numeric padding character) - if it isn't, then you know you're looking at the 3-character variant:

```
If Not IsNumeric(sCCNumber) Then sCCNumber = Right$(sCCNumber, 3)
```

Comment: Wow! That's awesome! Thanks Mathieu!!